# How to take character input in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf

```
char name[2];
scanf("%c",name);
printf("%c",name);
```

I am just starting to learn C. I'm curious about the above code, what I got from the printf output, is not the same with the character I typed in. Rather the output was some funny looking symbol. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `name` is an array, and `%c` expects a `char` (really expects an `int` argument); to print a `char`, use `printf("%c", name[0]);`, for example.

Comment: If you need to take an character array as input you should use scanf("%s",name), printf("%s",name); rather than using the %c . The %c returns the pointer to a character which cannn't be stored in pointer to character array.

Comment: scanf("%c",name)==>scanf("%s",name) and printf("%c",name)==>printf("%s",name);

Comment: name is not a char but a char [2]. Change the printf format

Comment: @sourabh1024 what? `%c` returns pointer to what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `%c` specifier, `scanf` needs the address of the location into which the character is to be stored, but `printf` needs the value of the character, not its address.  In C, an array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array when referenced.  So, the `scanf` is being passed the address of the first element of the `name` array, which is where the character will be stored; however, the `printf` is also being passed the address, which is wrong.  The `printf` should be like this:

```
printf("%c", name[0]);
```

Note that the `scanf` argument is technically ok, it is a little weird to be passing an array, when a pointer to a single character would suffice.  It would be better to declare a single character and pass its address explicitly:

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
printf("%c", c);
```

On the other hand, if you were trying to read a string instead of a single character, then you should be using `%s` instead of `%c`.

Answer (score 3):

Either Read a single char

```
char name[2];
scanf("%c",name);
printf("%c",name[0]);
```

Or read a string

```
char name[2];
scanf("%1s",name);
printf("%s",name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need %s since because name contains 2 elements. %c is used for single character so if you want the user to input something for e.g. "as"(without "") and the program to print it out you need %s.

```
char name[2];

scanf(" %s", name);
printf("%s",name);
```

Comment: The space before `%s` in `scanf(" %s", name);` is unnecessary. It cleans off any leading whitespace, but that would happen anyway with the `%s` format. But with the `%c` format in the question, it often *is* needed because in that case whitespace is *not* cleaned off unless you include that space.

Comment: @WeatherVane thats just how i learned to program and it stayed with me :D

Answer (score -2):

if you give your input which contains characters less than or equal to two you will get a correct output just as your input if your input contains characters  greater than 3 then it doesn't work

Comment: to read  a string that contains more no of characters just increase the character array to a[300] or a[no of chars in a string]

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP question, nor is it relevant to the behavior of the question. The question concerns about specifiers not input size.